# Customer checkout is not working, while guest checkout works

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

[image]

When I log in, there is no 'next' button on the checkout page like the image that I attached, so I can't place an order. But when I checkout as a guest, it works fine. Help me please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting next button because there are shipping methods coming up for the added address and logged in customer. Try again after enabling flat or free shipping from backend and it should come up.